# Is it possible to ignore Float :: = HexFloat and only see numeric characters?

Tags: java

I'm trying to parse the string value "87306E107" using hasNextDouble.  This value is a string and should return false when using hasNextDouble but it returns true.  I want know if it's possible to have this method return false?  The reason I want to treat this value as a string is because I have to wrap it in single quotes for building a dynamic database insert statement.  Here is my code below:

```
String data = "87306E107,27.1,xyz,123,01449J204";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(data);
scanner.useDelimiter(",");

if (!scanner.hasNextInt() && !scanner.hasNextDouble()){
    if (DateUtils.isDate(data)){
        //Format date to correct layout
        data = DateUtils.parseStringDate(data, "yyyy-MM-dd", 0);
    }
    //Escape any single quotes
    data = data.replaceAll("'", "''");
    //Wrap in single quotes
    data = "'" + data + "'";
}
```

Comment: But it is a double! (87306E107 = 87306 * 10 ^ 107)

Comment: I understand but is there a way to have hasNextDouble only read digits and not HexFloat values?  For instance, if I passed in the value "01449J204", hasNextDouble will read this a string.

Comment: I wouldn't use hasNextDouble() in that case.

Comment: String data is actually a comma separated list ("87306E107", 27.1, "xyz", 123) and I need to look for double 27.1 or int 123.  This is why I'm using hasNextDouble().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a string matcher instead of `hasNextDouble()`:

```
scanner.hasNext("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")
```

Comment: Ah, just beat me to it.  You're missing the `?` after the group though.

Comment: @MarkPeters Thank you, of course that was my intention for the group.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your responses.  This is the solution I'm going to use.